# PROXY protocol - test client /tool

Tags: haproxy, netcat, socat

[Proxy Protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.6/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) is implemented by [various software](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/use-the-proxy-protocol-to-preserve-a-clients-ip-address/) including of course HAProxy itself.

When testing from a host via a proxy, it would be useful to have a simple command-line tool to establish connections, controlling the various parameters.

I've looked at netcat, socat and [other similar tools](https://github.com/vi/websocat/issues/37) and it looks like it doesn't (yet) exist.

Does anyone know of a nice command-line testing tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't find something, here's [a start](https://github.com/tuck1s/happie). Will add documentation etc. shortly.